# autofill cell values based on upper cell values in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have customer purchase data which is exported from SQL database. The output format in Google sheets looks like this:

```
ID  name   address          phone       product name
1   Bob    2030 random road 6265609245  A
1                                       B
2   Peter  5453 golden drive            A
2                                       D
3   Jason  1 dna way                    C
4   James  sfo drive                    A
4                                       B
4                                       C
```

I'd like to know if I could autofill the blank cells with the upper cell values if they have the same ID. To illustrate this please see the desired output format below:

```
ID  name   address          phone       product name
1   Bob    2030 random road 6265609245  A
1   Bob    2030 random road 6265609245  B
2   Peter  5453 golden drive            A
2   Peter  5453 golden drive            D
3   Jason  1 dna way                    C
4   James  sfo drive                    A
4   James  sfo drive                    B
4   James  sfo drive                    C
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: with formula you can but in new table

Comment: You don't have the `google-apps-script` tag, but would you be open for an Apps Script solution? That could eaily solve your case. If you prefer a formula one you probably would need to use another table as @player0 has suggested.

Comment: @player0 would you explain more? Thanks!

Comment: @Raserhin I probably forgot to add that tag but yes I am open to any solution! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to complete the row based on the ID. If my assumption is correct, you can use this Apps Script code:

```
function so62048323() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();
  var nameDictionary = new Object();
  var addressDictionary = new Object();
  var phoneDictionary = new Object();

  for (var r = 1; r < data.length; r++) {
    if (data[r][0] != '') {
      if (data[r][1] != '') {
        nameDictionary[data[r][0]] = data[r][1];
      }
      if (data[r][2] != '') {
        addressDictionary[data[r][0]] = data[r][2];
      }
      if (data[r][3] != '') {
        phoneDictionary[data[r][0]] = data[r][3];
      }
    }
  }

  for (var r = 1; r < data.length; r++) {
    if (data[r][1] == '') {
      data[r][1] = nameDictionary[data[r][0]];
    }
    if (data[r][2] == '') {
      data[r][2] = addressDictionary[data[r][0]]
    }
    if (data[r][3] == '') {
      data[r][3] = phoneDictionary[data[r][0]];
    }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().setValues(data)
}
```

The code will initiate reading all your table with [`SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive), [`Spreadsheet.getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). After that it will create three [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as dictionaries.

After that the code will iterate each row and record in the dictionaries each value (name, phone and address) associated with the ID. Afterwards, the code will repeat the operation but writing down the values. Finally, all the data is loaded in the sheet with Range.setValues(). For example, if we have this spreadsheet:

[image: Initial spreadsheet]

And we use the script, we will end up with this:

[image: Final step]

Please, notice how some ID doesn't have any phones; these are left empty. I understand that you may be using a very big database, so I optimized the code so it will run the fastest possible without taking into account the data size. Also, this code will work even if the rows aren't ordered. Don't hesitate to ask me any question if you have doubts.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! Thanks!